# Finding the number of edges leading to a user's photo

Tags: python, facebook, web

I haven't ventured into looking at open graph calls on finding the number of edges a photo has ( by edges, I mean comments/likes/tags ) but would like to know if it's possible.

Specifically, I'm looking to (after being authorized) scrape through the users pictures and find out what photos have the most number of likes/comments/tags. Can this be done through GRAPH calls?

I've worked with some graph calls before, but never for photos. I'm primarily a C and iOS/Cocoa/Obj-C developer. I am using Python (learning it and using this project as my motivation) to make this a web app.

It's okay for the app to take some time to retrieve the photos - it's expected and I do not expect the users to repeatedly return to this app.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with FQL. This will get you a list of your photos ordered by descending number of likes.

```
SELECT object_id, created, src, like_info, comment_info FROM photo WHERE owner = me() 
   ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC
```

Counting tags is trickier since neither the Graph API nor FQL have a count method, and there is no `tag_info` field.